Error message: The parameter "api3_permissions" must be defined
After upgrading to 5.73.2, I get the following message for a number of actions, e.g. removing a contact from a group on the contact page. (Removing it from the group page does work). As the second error indicates, it looks that something with contactactivity is causing this.
I do not see any references for api3 and this error. Anyone have a clue?
[error] 

$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "The parameter "api3_permissions" must be defined."
"code" => null
"exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#1922
#message: "The parameter "api3_permissions" must be defined."
#code: 0
#file: "/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php"
#line: 138
#cause: null
-_trace: null
-errorData: array:3 [
"is_error" => 1
"error_message" => "The parameter "api3_permissions" must be defined."
"error_code" => "undefined"
]
trace: {
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php:138 {
civicrm_api3(string $entity, string $action, array $params = [])
› if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['is_error'])) {
›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception($result['error_message'], $result['error_code'] ?? 'undefined', $result);
› }
}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php:612 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php:2356 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Activity/Page/AJAX.php:430 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:291 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:470 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/includes/menu.inc:527 { …}
/home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/index.php:21 { …}
}
}
]
2024-06-08 10:59:02+0200  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(470): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "contactactivity")
#4 /home/user/domains/mydomain/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#5 {main}

I disabled all extensions which referenced the api and it turns out that CivimobileAPI is the cause.
